# Not showing data when adding data to array

Tags: react-native

I recently incorporated real-time database to my react-native app.

The problem is that a new object is shown, but it is shown with a "Lorem Ipsum" and I don't know how to fix it.

I'm adding the data the following way:

```
.listen('HomeworkCreated', ev => this.setState({ 
                homeworks: [ev, ...this.state.homeworks]  // Here :)
           }));
```

I'm pretty sure this is the problem, as it does render in the view a new object when a new object is created. Now, the thing is that we need to somehow add that data to the new object.

I already did a `console.log` and it does follow the same structure as the other ones.

This is what I get from `ev`:

```
Object {
  "homework": Object {
    "completed": 0,
    "created_at": "2020-06-20T12:22:04.000000Z",
    "description": "Test",
    "duedate": "2020-06-20T12:21:55.663Z",
    "id": 60,
    "image": null,
    "progress": 30,
    "subject": Object {
      "created_at": "2020-06-19T15:46:37.000000Z",
      "icon": "subjectImgs/14-1080x1080.jpg",
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Test",
      "updated_at": "2020-06-19T15:46:37.000000Z",
      "user_id": 1,
    },
    "subject_id": 10,
    "title": "Consolé est",
    "updated_at": "2020-06-20T12:22:04.000000Z",
    "user_id": 1,
  },
  "socket": null,
}
```

This is what I get in the `this.state.homeworks`:

```
  Object {
    "completed": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-06-17T09:56:29.000000Z",
    "description": "test",
    "duedate": "2020-06-20",
    "id": 2,
    "image": "uploads/atFl3P4SLnjaZ0Db9HFfqMIPefe8NOlDwHT5kRQK.jpeg",
    "progress": 100,
    "subject_id": 1,
    "title": "Test",
    "updated_at": "2020-06-17T09:56:40.000000Z",
    "user_id": 1,
  },
  Object {
    "completed": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-06-04T18:45:06.000000Z",
    "description": "test",
    "duedate": "2020-06-22",
    "id": 1,
    "image": "uploads/BmcrIk4UjmNT8l2z9sxKq9MEgi4Mt1poQGra5Xyw.jpeg",
    "progress": 100,
    "subject_id": 1,
    "title": "test",
    "updated_at": "2020-06-17T09:56:07.000000Z",
    "user_id": 1,
  },
]
Array [
  Object {
    "completed": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-06-17T09:56:29.000000Z",
    "description": "test",
    "duedate": "2020-06-20",
    "id": 2,
    "image": "uploads/atFl3P4SLnjaZ0Db9HFfqMIPefe8NOlDwHT5kRQK.jpeg",
    "progress": 100,
    "subject_id": 1,
    "title": "Test",
    "updated_at": "2020-06-17T09:56:40.000000Z",
    "user_id": 1,
  },
  Object {
    "completed": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-06-04T18:45:06.000000Z",
    "description": "test",
    "duedate": "2020-06-22",
    "id": 1,
    "image": "uploads/BmcrIk4UjmNT8l2z9sxKq9MEgi4Mt1poQGra5Xyw.jpeg",
    "progress": 100,
    "subject_id": 1,
    "title": "test",
    "updated_at": "2020-06-17T09:56:07.000000Z",
    "user_id": 1,
  },
]
```

Comment: What do you see if you console log `ev` and `this.state.homeworks` before you call `setState`? What exactly is the problem? That you are receiving incorrect data or that it's not setting properly in state? Or that it isn't rendering?

Comment: @James The data is correct, what I get on ev is the the new object that was created. I can log and show you, but its still the same thing... I already checked it.

Comment: @James just updated the post, check it out.

Comment: Oh, now I realized the problem :)

Comment: I had to do: `ev.homework` instead of just `ev`

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @James you indeed helped :) thanks!